# Are the first two letters of "jung" and "jünger" sometimes pronounced the same?

Tags: pronunciation

According to the letters the sounds in the beginning of "jung" is [ju] and in the beginning of "jünger" is [jy].

While is there synaeresis (even "j" is regarded as a consonant) combining [ju] or [jy] into the same vowel [y]?

And are the vowels got loose in these words, so we get [ø]?

Comment: The last line seems to be a separate question, and I don't understand that one. What is *get loose* supposed to mean?

Answer (score 5):

I have never heard of ju and jü pronounced the same. (I am not native, but live here for a while) In German language the written form and the pronounced sounds have a clear and strong connection. You might have heard somebody speaking in dialect.

Answer (score 5):

German has a relatively strict mapping between sounds and letters. You can find this mapping-rules in this document, in § 1: [Regeln und Wörterverzeichnis](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf)

Some of these rules are:

> - The short vowels [ʊ] and [u] and the long vowel [u:] are written with the letter »u«
>     ([u:] sometimes also as »uh«)
> - The short vowels [ʏ] and [y] and the long vowel [y:] are written with the letter »ü«
>     ([y:] sometimes also as »üh«)
> - The short vowels [œ] and [ø] and the long vowel [ø:] are written with the letter »ö«

Examples:

> - Mund = [mʊnt]
> - zuvor = [ʦuˈfoːɐ̯]
> - gut = [ɡuːt]
> - Kuh =  [kuː]
> - hübsch = [hʏpʃ]
> - Büro = [byˈʀoː]
> - trüb = [tʀyːp]
> - kühl = [kyːl]
> - löschen = [ˈlœʃn̩]
> - Ökonomie = [ˌøkonoˈmiː]
> - schön = [ʃøːn]

Conclusions of this rules are (for German words only):

> - The letter u is never pronounced as [ʏ], [y], [y:], [œ], [ø] or [ø:].
> - The letter ü is never pronounced as [ʊ], [u], [u:], [œ], [ø] or [ø:].
> - The letter ö is never pronounced as [ʊ], [u], [u:], [ʏ], [y] or [y:].

Note, that this rules apply only for German words. There are exceptions for foreign words like »Buffet« = [bʏˈfeː] which are pronounced very similar to the pronunciation in their original language (French in case of *Buffet*).

*Jung* is a German word, which means, that it obeys these rules. So, the pronunciation of *jung* and *jünger* are:

> - *jung* = [jʊŋ]
> - *jünger* = [ˈjʏŋɐ]

Note, that in German there also exist some minimal pairs for [ʊ]-[ʏ]

- Mutter - Mütter (mother, mothers)

  > [ˈmʊtɐ] - [ˈmʏtɐ]
- drucken - drücken (print, press)

  > [ˈdʀʊkn̩] - [ˈdʀʏkn̩]

I have heart some northern dialects, where the letter »i« sometimes is pronounced as [ʏ] instead of [ɪ] (»Fische« = [fʏʃə] instead of [fɪʃə]), but I'm not aware of any German dialect, where »u« is pronounced like »ü« or vice versa. And I also don't know any German dialect, where »u« or »ü« would sound like »ö«.

In German there also is no synaeresis that would eliminate the consonant [j] before any vowel.

Comment: There *are* some north-german dialects (or rather more, regional specialties) that pronounce "i" as "ü" or even close to "ö" - "*Kirche/Kürche/Körche*" (Braunschweig area). I have, however, never heard this in "jünger".